losing focus as soon as I type a character. any help would be appreciated
I am implementing a sortable tree for a nested object using the dnd-kit-sortable-tree library. Each tree item includes an input field for editing its value. However, I am encountering an issue where the input field loses focus every time I type a character.
Details:
•   The tree is managed as a nested object in state.
•   Each tree item is rendered with a unique key and a ref.
•   The state is updated whenever a character is typed into an input field.
Issue:
As soon as I type a character in an input field, the input loses focus. I suspect this is caused by re-renders triggered by the state update, but I am unsure how to prevent this while maintaining the sortable functionality and proper state management.
Minimal Implementation:
Here’s a simplified version of my current implementation:
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { SimpleTreeItemWrapper, SortableTree } from "dnd-kit-sortable-tree";
import sizeof from "object-sizeof";

export default function NestedSortableTree() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialViableMinimalData);

  console.log(sizeof(items), items, "bytes");

  const handleItemChange = (itemId, newValue) => {
    setItems((prevItems) => {
      // Recursively find and update the item by ID
      const updateItems = (nodes) =>
        nodes.map((node) => {
          if (node.id === itemId) {
            return { ...node, value: newValue };
          }
          if (node.children) {
            return { ...node, children: updateItems(node.children) };
          }
          return node;
        });

      return updateItems(prevItems);
    });
  };

  return (
    <SortableTree
      items={items}
      onItemsChanged={setItems} // For drag-and-drop updates
      TreeItemComponent={(props) => (
        <TreeItem {...props} onItemChange={handleItemChange} />
      )}
    />
  );
}

const TreeItem = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  console.log(props)
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const [sample, setSample] = useState(props.item.value);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus(); // Ensure input retains focus
    }
  }, [props.item.id]); // Trigger refocus only when the specific item changes

  const onChange = (event) => {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    setSample(newValue); // Update local state for immediate feedback
    props.onItemChange(props.item.id, newValue); // Update the global state
  };

  return (
    <SimpleTreeItemWrapper {...props} ref={ref} disableCollapseOnItemClick>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        className="border"
        value={sample}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </SimpleTreeItemWrapper>
  );
});

const initialViableMinimalData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: "Jane",
    children: [
      { id: 4, value: "John", type: "text" },
      { id: 5, value: "Sally" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "Fred",
    children: [
      {
        id: 6,
        value: "Eugene",
        children: [
          { id: 7, value: "John" },
          { id: 8, value: "Sally" },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  { id: 3, value: "Helen" },
];

